# Laravel redirect from blade with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've a route with a parameter in my laravel application.

```
Route::get('news/update/{id?}', 'Admin\NewsController@update')->name('news.update');
```

How can I redirect from a blade view to the route with the parameter?

```
{{ route('news.update', ['id' => $_news['id']]) }}
```

This code redirects only to `news/update?id=1`

Does anyone has an idea?

**Edit:** The Site returns only data form a database based on the id parameter. So the GET method is ok. The parameter is optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ route('news.update', $_news['id']) }}
```

Try that. also, update routes probably should be `Route::put()`

Comment: Yes because you need to change it from get to put.

Comment: But the route returns a view. So I can't change it to put

Comment: Clear your cache and your browser cache, because it should work.... php artisan cache:clear

Comment: It's a server issue then not a laravel issue. Unless you have a resource controller below that route... post your whole web.php file

Answer (score 0):

are you sure update with use get ?

use `{id}` instead of `{id?}` on update

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The Page only display informations based on this id. With `{id}` the parameter isn't optional.

Comment: `/news/update` or `/news/update/any_long_string` also will goes to your route 'news.update', can you dd($_news['id'])